# Observable array from another JSON object with child arrays

Tags: arrays, json, knockout.js, observable

I am trying to initialize an observable array from a json object which is rendered from the server as Javascript/Json;

Basically I have a simple model (from the server) that looks like this

```
    var BaseModel = { "changeRequestLocations": 
             [{ "location": "New Zealand", "devices": 
                      [
                        { "id": "5", "deviceName": "Server 1" },  
                        { "id": "6", "deviceName": "Server 2" }
                      ],
              "id": 1 }] };
```

I then initialize an observable array from the baseModel

```
    this.changeRequestLocations = ko.observableArray(BaseModel.changeRequestLocations);
```

This basically does what I want but the "devices" element is an **array** not an **observable array**.

I really need to have it as an observable array - is there a way to tell Knockout to do this automatically or do I need to do it manually?

[See a fiddle here that shows the case](http://jsfiddle.net/iisfaq/4vGgL/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In itself Knockout does not do this for you automatically, so

- you do it manually like your jsfiddle
- you use the [Knockout.Mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) which is designed for this scenario: convert plain JavaScript objects to objects with observable properties.

So in your example you just need to write:

```
this.changeRequestLocations = ko.mapping.fromJS(BaseModel.changeRequestLocations);
```

and the mapping plugin will convert your `location` array into an observable array.

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zKRmM/).